# What is a good design for a method that can return several logically different results?

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented

The question title is probably too abstract, so let me provide a particular example of what I have in mind:

There is a webservice that encapsulates a process of changing passwords for users of a distributed system. The webservice accepts user's login, his old password and a new password. Based on this input, it can return one of the following three results:

1. In case user was not found, or his old password does not match, it will simply return with HTTP 403 Forbidden.
2. Otherwise, it takes a new password and makes sure that it conforms to a password policy (e.g. it is long enough, contains a proper mix of letters and numbers, etc.). If it does not, it will return an XML describing why the password does not conform to the policy.
3. Otherwise, it will change the password and return an XML containing an expiration date of the new password.

Now, I'd like to design a class, ideally with a single method, to encapsulate working with this webservice. My first shot was this:

```
public class PasswordManagementWebService
{
    public ChangePasswordResult ChangePassword(string login, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        ChangePasswordResult result;

        // send input to websevice, it's not important how; the httpResponse
        // will contain a response from webservice
        var httpResponse;
        if (HasAuthenticationFailed(httpResponse)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }
        else if (WasPasswordSuccessfullyChanged(httpResponse))
        {
            result = new ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult(httpResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            result = new ChangePasswordUnsuccessfulResult(httpResponse);
        }

        return result;
    }
}    

public abstract class ChangePasswordResult
{
    public abstract bool WasSuccessful { get; }
}

public abstract class ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult
{
    public ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult(HttpResponse  httpResponse)
    {
        // initialize the class from the httpResponse
    }

    public override bool WasSuccessful { get { return true; } }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class ChangePasswordUnsuccessfulResult
{
    public ChangePasswordUnsuccessfulResult(HttpResponse  httpResponse)
    {
        // initialize the class from the httpResponse
    }

    public override bool WasSuccessful { get { return false; } }

    public bool WasPasswordLongEnough { get; private set; }        
    public bool DoesPasswordHaveToContainNumbers { get; private set; }
    // ... etc.         
}
```

As you can see, I've decided to use separate classes for return cases #2 and #3 - I could have used a single class with a boolean, but it feels like a smell, the class would have no clear purpose. With two separate classes, an user of my `PasswordManagementWebService` class now has to know which classes inherit from `ChangePasswordResult` and to cast to a correct one based on the `WasSuccessful` property. While I now do have a nice, laser-focused classes, I made a life of my users more difficult than it should be.

As for the case #1, I've just decided to throw an exception. I could have created a separate exception for the case #2, too, and only return something from the method when the password *was* successfully changed. However, this doesn't feel right - I don't think that a new password being invalid is a state exceptional enough to warrant throwing an exception.

I am not very sure how would I design things were there more than two un-exceptional result types from the webservice. Probably, I would change a type of `WasSuccessful` property from boolean to an enum and rename it to `ResultType`, adding a dedicated class inherited from `ChangePasswordResult` for each possible `ResultType`.

Finally, to the **actual question:** Is this design approach (i.e. having one abstract class and forcing clients to cast to a correct result based on a property) a correct one when dealing with problems like this? If yes, is there a way to improve it (perhaps with a different strategy for when to throw exceptions vs. return results)? If no, what would you recommend?

Comment: See [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159804/how-do-you-encode-algebraic-data-types-in-a-c-or-java-like-language) for a solution that doesn't involve casting.

Comment: @Doval Do you mean the answer from Joey Adams? If yes, then I'm deducing the solution would probably involve the `ChangePassword` to accept two `Action`s, one accepting the `ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult` and the other `ChangePasswordUnsuccessfulResult`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that answer. You can use `Either` as-is and return `Either<ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult, ChangePasswordUnsuccessfulResult>`. The user can call `match` with two lambdas to take a decision based on the type of result without doing any casting. The only change I'd make to that implementation of `Either` would be to give it a `private` constructor and make `Left` and `Right` private inner classes so no one can add new subclasses and break it.

Comment: One more thing - if you're going to go with my approach, I would recommend *against* throwing an exception. The client code already has to do some branching for the different success cases; it's better to add the failure case to the return value so it can be handled in the same way. If you don't, the client has to do branching twice using two different mechanisms - a try/catch plus the call to the `match` method.

Comment: If C# had any kind of native support for ADTs (or if I was using a functional language like F#), I'd certainly go that way. Since this is something C# lacks, I don't suppose I would ever find a way to implement some pseudo-ADT to be immediately obvious and clear for an average C# programmer. Right now, I am torn between leaving it just as desribed in OP, or using exceptions for everything except successful password change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't subscribe to the school of thought which says "exceptions should only be for exceptional cases!" People are scared of exceptions for some reason. If you can't do what you said you're going to do, throw an exception - even if it's a common or expected failure.

I like this for a few reasons. It's impossible for the caller to ignore (someone could easily forget to inspect the return value of a method that indicates failure by a return code.) It's simple (no special placeholder values for missing results or hierarchies which need downcasting.) It's atomic (either my change succeeded or you tell me to get lost; I'm left in no doubt as to which it is.) It's granular (you can attach as much information as you like to the exception, and throw different exceptions for different failures.)

So I'd design your method like this:

```
public void ChangePassword(string password)
{
    HttpResponse response = RequestPasswordChange();
    if (AuthFailed(response))
        throw new AuthorizationException();
    if (PasswordWasNotChanged(response))
        throw new InvalidNewPasswordException(
            WasPasswordLongEnough(response),
            DidPasswordContainNumbers(response)
        );
}
```

"Succeed-or-throw" is a fine rule of thumb, and people *are* used to it, no matter how much they wave their arms. After all, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` throws `KeyNotFoundException` when you fail to index into it. A non-exceptional use of exceptions.

Comment: "*People are scared of exceptions for some reason*" - sure, because in most (not all) languages a *raised* exception has a significant performance impact. Next reason is that an exception changes the program flow [in an sometimes unexpected way](http://www.siberas.de/papers/Pwn2Own_2014_AFD.sys_privilege_escalation.pdf). Exceptions have their place and are a good tool, [if you do it right](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/09/10/228068.aspx).

Comment: The questioneer's code is making HTTP requests. I don't think an exception is going to make an appreciable difference to the performance. I agree that you can't stop clients from handling exceptions badly, but you also can't stop them from ignoring return codes (which I'd argue is an easier mistake to make)

Comment: Sure. And how is the "*old school of thought*" related to HTTP requests? Just asking.

Comment: "which I'd argue is an easier mistake to make": This depends on the language you are using. If your language supports algebraic data types, then the error code is just an extra option in your return data type and the compiler will complain if you do not handle it in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I am now convinced that ADTs are exactly what I need. In C#, however, I suppose it really comes down to a choice between a return code and an exception. Solution I described in OP is basically about return codes. I'd say it's more likely that client will notice that there are two classes inheriting from `ChangePasswordResult` and start thinking about what it means - to notice the method can throw an exception, he would have to open up docs and really, what is a chance of that happening? Declared exceptions would help here, but this is another thing C# lacks....

Comment: @Giorgio: yes, algebraic data types are a wonderful alternative to exceptions in a language which supports them. The original question was about C# though.

Comment: @JensG I don't understand your question

Comment: @NikolaAnusev - "it's more likely the client will notice there are two classes inheriting from ChangePasswordResult and start thinking" - I disagree. Downcasting is a profoundly un-C#ish thing to do and clients are unlikely to 'get it' right away. Yes, there is always the chance that the client won't realise the exception can be thrown - that's why we need QAs to break our code for us ;)

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson: Fair enough. You can still simulate them using subclassing, even though I admit that it is not as convenient as using algebraic data types, and probably you should resort to some trick to have the compiler warn you when you haven't covered all the possible cases.

Answer (score 3):

I think this approach is over-using inheritance which adds additional (unnecessary) complexity. Favor composition over inheritance when possible. Especially if it's a Success/Non-Success thing that is easily represented with a boolean it doesn't warrant the need for sub-classing.

You could include everything you need to into a single class, and based on the result you can use the properties accordingly. The class still has a single purpose, to return information about the password change. The fact that there are several different outcomes is an essential complexity of the task.

```
class ChangePasswordResult
{
    public bool Result { get; private set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; private set; }  
    public bool WasPasswordLongEnough { get; private set; }        
    public bool DoesPasswordHaveToContainNumbers { get; private set; }
}
```

Edit:

jhewlett Brings up a very good point too about serialization. With a single result structure being returned you have a more stable interface clients can interact with. When you document your interface you can say "this endpoint returns X" as opposed to "this endpoint returns X OR Y depending on..."

Comment: +1, especially considering that the result will be serialized to xml or json in this case

Comment: "The fact that there are several different outcomes is an essential complexity of the task." Which is exactly why returning the *union of all possible outcomes* is the wrong thing to do. Now the client must figure out which fields are applicable to the current outcome. I agree with favoring composition, but Nikola isn't *really* trying to use inheritance. He needs a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), which C# and Java lack, but can be implemented with inheritance in a way that hides the inheritance tree from the client (see my comments to the question.)

Comment: @Doval I'm not sure what you mean by "he isn't really using inheritance". He has a base class, and a subclass for each outcome. Regarding the extra properties, I don't see the success/error results being so wildly different that it creates problems. In a successful password change, WasPasswordLongEnough and DoesPasswordHaveEnoughNumbers are still valid. In a bad password result you have ONE property that you wouldn't use, ExpirationDate (I removed NewPassword property which wasn't supposed to be there).  Which leads me to the same conclusion that a tagged union is also unnecessary in this case

Comment: What I meant by that comment is that he's using inheritance to create a closed union (i.e. there's a fixed number of possibilities) of POCO result objects, as opposed to creating an actual *object* whose methods can be overwritten. And as long as there's at least one property that must be ignored, you've inconvenienced the client. If `ExpirationDate` is left `null`, there's potential for an exception at runtime. If you avoid null ([which you should](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/12777/116461)) the client has to unbox a `Maybe`/`Optional`.

Comment: I don't like this solution very much exactly because of reasons mentioned by @Doval - returning an _union_ reeks of bad design. As for "favoring composition over inheritance", I may be wrong, but does it really apply in this case? I always thought that the meaning of the rule is that when there is some common functionality that needs to be reused in multiple places, one should favor creating class _A_ encapsulating this common stuff and then reusing it in classes _B_ and _C_ by instantiating _A_ rather than having _B_ and _C_ inheriting from _A_.

Comment: @Doval DateTime is a value type which cannot be null. I disagree that this is somehow inconvenient to the client. I would say it is the MOST convenient solution. I call a method, I get a result and I can base my logic off the Result property. Very simple and straightforward. This simplicity comes with the trade-off of having the a property the client won't need, I price I would be willing to pay. I will often favor practicality and simplicity over theoretical correctness. A good example I can give is the composite pattern. Not all nodes will have children or even be possible...

Comment: ..that they have children, but it doesn't inconvenience me in the least that the node has a Children property. It greatly simplifies my interface I interact with, I don't have to do any checking and casting between types, and it doesn't do harm.

Comment: @NikolaAnusev Yes, I think it does apply to your situation. You have created a class hierarchy where one subclass represents an Unsuccessful result and one that represents a Successful result. You can instead encapsulate the functionality of indicating the result in a boolean property. You have replaced inheritance with composition. With inheritance your class IS the result (IS-A relationship), with composition your class HAS a result (HAS-A relationshhip).

Comment: @NikolaAnusev It is somewhat hidden by the fact that your sub classes also have a WasSuccessful property, but this property is redundant. A ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult class should never have WasSuccessful set to false and vice versa. To prove that you baked the success indicator into the class, you can remove that property and still check with the `is` keyword. if (result is ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult) { /* do something */ }

Answer (score 0):

I would assume there is different action when `WasSuccessful` is `true` and different action when `WasSuccessful` is `false`. Why not put this code inside of `ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult` and `ChangePasswordUnsuccessfulResult` and call it through virtual method, thus deciding based on the type. Then, you don't have to worry about casting.

```
public abstract class ChangePasswordResult
{
    public abstract SomeResponseData GetResponseData();
}

public class ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult
{
    public ChangePasswordSuccessfulResult(HttpResponse  httpResponse)
    {
        // initialize the class from the httpResponse
    }

    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; private set; }

    public override SomeResponseData GetResponseData()
    {
        // return data for successful result
    }
}

public abstract class ChangePasswordUnsuccessfulResult
{
    public ChangePasswordUnsuccessfulResult(HttpResponse  httpResponse)
    {
        // initialize the class from the httpResponse
    }

    public bool WasPasswordLongEnough { get; private set; }        
    public bool DoesPasswordHaveToContainNumbers { get; private set; }
    // ... etc.         

    public override SomeResponseData GetResponseData()
    {
        // return data for unsuccessful result
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, there is a different action for each outcome. However, in this particular case, both actions have something to do with updating UI and I wouldn't like putting UI code to those `Result` classes.

Comment: @NikolaAnusev If you want to be really precise about it, you could define a factory interface, that creates the "results" and then inject the implementation of that factory that returns "results" that can update UI. That way you maintain the separation, but you just added 2 more entities and bunch of coupling to solve this problem.

Comment: .. But that makes it hard to add new results. I guess it is not that good idea.